# Docker build with python-3.10-alpine

Tags: python, dockerfile

I am facing compatability issue with python-3.10-alpine when building the docker image.

Requirements.txt

```
numpy==1.21.2
dask==2021.9.1
pandas==1.4.4
pyrrow==8.0.0
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.10-apine
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

`docker build .`
While installing pandas it throws an error Numpy 1.21.6 may not yet supported by 3.10

Comment: Even though you called out `numpy==1.21.2`, one of the other packages may require `1.21.6`.  You'll need to check the dependencies of each install to see who is causing this requirement to be triggered, than roll back that version number.  Do you have any more of pip's output?